# partial page update in jquery Simple Request

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have simple request 
I'm beginner in jquery so all i want to do is to do

button when i click it increment counter variable and  update only label on page 
not all page 
also i will use same code to make clock in page 
thank you

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Without you trying some code it is hard to be of specific help, but here is how to read a click, increment a counter, update a label, and call a make clock function.

```
$(function() {
  function incrementCounter() {
    var $counter = $('#counter'),
        count = parseInt($counter).text());

    if (!count) count = 0;
    count++;
    $counter.text(count);
  }

  function updateLabel(newText) {
    $('label').text(newText);
  }

  function makeClock() {
    // I have no idea what you mean by this but insert your code here.
  }

  $('button').click(function() {
    incrementCounter();
    updateLabel();
    makeClock();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The increment one you can do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function() {
        current = parseInt($('#label').html());
        $('#label').html(current+1);
    });
});
</script>

<input type='button' value=' Increase! ' id='button' />
Count: <span id='label'>0</span>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you tried to say. If this doesn't work for you then show us the html you have in mind to try and add the jQuery behavior accordingly.